# Obj-C - TableView scroll to bottom after data reloaded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to have my tableview scroll to the bottom after new data is loaded. For example I have a chat window that is loading new messages once my 'sendReply' button is pressed, and I always want it to scroll to the most recent message (at the bottom) when data is posted. For some reason, my tableView won't scroll to the bottom after self.tableview reload?

I assume this is because of *rowNumber-1* in my method, but when I try to change this to -0, I get the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '-[UITableView
>   _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:usingPresentationValues:]:
>   row (16) beyond bounds (16) for section (0).'

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)scrollTableToBottom {
    NSInteger rowNumber = [self. tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];
    if (rowNumber > 0) {
        [self. tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowNumber-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }
}

- (IBAction)sendReply:(id)sender {


    if ([self.messageData count] > 0) {

        self.sendButton.hidden = YES;

        self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];


    NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [nodeData setObject:@"messages" forKey:@"type"];


    NSDictionary *messageValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.replyField.text, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *finalMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:messageValues] forKey:@"und"];

    [nodeData setObject:finalMessage forKey:@"body"];

   NSString *otherUID = [self.messageData objectForKey:@"uid"];



    NSString *userValue = otherUID;


    NSDictionary *targetMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:userValue, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
    NSDictionary *finalUser = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:targetMessage] forKey:@"und"];

    [nodeData setObject:finalUser forKey:@"field_targetuser"];

    [nodeData setValue: @"Re:" forKey:@"title"];

        NSDictionary *userDictInfo = (NSDictionary*) [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"diosSession"]];


        DIOSSession *session = [DIOSSession sharedSession];
        [session setUser:userDictInfo];


        [session user];


    NSString *uid = [session user][@"user"][@"uid"];


    [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


           self.replyField.text = @"";
            [self.tableView reloadData];
             [self scrollTableToBottom];
             self.sendButton.hidden = NO;
             [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
             self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
    }];



    } else if ([self.messageDataFriends count] > 0) {

        self.sendButton.hidden = YES;

        self.activityIndicator.hidden = NO;
        [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

        NSMutableDictionary *nodeData = [NSMutableDictionary new];

        [nodeData setObject:@"messages" forKey:@"type"];


        NSDictionary *messageValues = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.replyField.text, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
        NSDictionary *finalMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:messageValues] forKey:@"und"];

        [nodeData setObject:finalMessage forKey:@"body"];


        NSString *otherUID = [self.messageDataFriends objectForKey:@"uid2"];



        NSString *userValue = otherUID;

        NSDictionary *targetMessage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:userValue, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value", nil]];
        NSDictionary *finalUser = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:targetMessage] forKey:@"und"];

        [nodeData setObject:finalUser forKey:@"field_targetuser"];


        [nodeData setValue: @"Re:" forKey:@"title"];


        NSString *uid = [[[DIOSSession sharedSession] user] objectForKey:@"uid"];



        [DIOSNode nodeSave:nodeData success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                self.replyField.text = @"";


                [self.tableView reloadData];
                       [self scrollTableToBottom];
                self.sendButton.hidden = NO;
                 [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
                self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;


            });




        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Node did not save!");
        }];


    }


}
```

Comment: You need the `-1` since the last row is "count - 1". You say the table doesn't scroll to the bottom. What does it actually do when you call your `scrollTableToBottom` method? Also, do you realize that you are not calling `reloadData` and `scrollTableToBottom` on the main thread in 1 of your 2 calls to `DIOSNode nodeSave`?

Comment: @rmaddy The table scrolls to the second last cell (so it does scroll to the 'bottom', but not the VERY bottom - which is the newly added cell). If I call scrollTableToBottom before data reload, indeed, it scrolls to the very bottom.

Comment: Can you scroll the actual last row into view by hand after that?

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I can

Answer (score 1):

1. Add to the first block

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       self.replyField.text = @"";
       [self.tableView reloadData];
       [self scrollTableToBottom];
       self.sendButton.hidden = NO;
       [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
       self.activityIndicator.hidden = YES;
   });
   ```
2. Also add `NSLog(@"rowNumber = %lu",rowNumber);` after `NSInteger
   rowNumber = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0];` in
   scrollTableToBottom method. And before `[self.tableView reloadData];`
   If they are equal, this means that the data have not been reloaded yet.

Comment: If this is the case, than how can I have it scroll to the very bottom only once new data is loaded?

Comment: @Brittany, I don't know.